# UKVI helpline Question

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I called UKVI helpline and inquired about my application. They said its concluded and a decision has been made, and relevant department will contact you once ready for delivery.
Anybody knows how much time do they get to make it ready for delivery, because i didnt receive any email from UK embassy yet.